# C: defining multidimensional arrays in a switch

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, switch-statement

I'm translating code from Maple to C in order to optimize performance. In order to save time, I've hard coded a 2-dimensional array for the 3 cases that I need to run asap. Later I'll add functions that generate this array so that I can run any case.

Here's how I tried to define the array `schur`: (here `N` and `dim` are pre-determined `int`s, and `numPar` is an `int` as well).

```
  // load Schur functions
  switch (N) {
  case 3: 
    numPar = 3;
    int schur[numPar][dim] = {
      {1,0,0,0},
      {0,1,1,0},
      {0,0,0,1},
    };  
    break;

  case 4:
    numPar = 5;
    int schur[numPar][dim] = {
      {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
      {0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0},
      {0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0},
      {0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0},
      {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
    };    
    break;

  case 5: 
    numPar = 7;
    int schur[numPar][dim] = {
      {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
      {0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
      {0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0},
      {0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0},
      {0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0},
      {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0},
      {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
    };        
    break;

  default:  
  }
```

Clearly this will not work. However, I'm at a loss as to how to rewrite it so that it does work. One idea is to flatten the array, but that will obfuscate my code rather badly later on. Suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a formula for `schur[i][j]`? If so, you can create your VLA and then loop through the array to initialize.  (You'll have to loop through the array anyway to initialize no matter what.)

Comment: I presume in your real code, dim is being adjusted along with numPar, since your array sizes vary in both directions.... 

If you're going to be deciding the size at runtime, the usual approach is to obtain the space from the heap. Some of the answers at the right under "Related" should help.

Comment: @tabstop No. To generate that I need to write three very complication functions.

Comment: @keshlam `N` is fixed at run time; `dim` is 2^(N-1)` and `numPar` is the number of partitions of `N`, hence both are constant for a given run.

Comment: @PengOne Your sketch code above sets numPar, but doesn't set dim, though the arrays clearly showed dim being different from case to case, so I wanted to make sure we understood what was going on.

Comment: @PengOne why not dynamic memory allocation using malloc() ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can allocate the multidimensional array to be as large as the largest case. Based on the switch case you can only fill it to the size you need, and then only access it to the size you filled.

So for example for the 3 by 4 array:

```
int staticArray[3][4] = {
  {1,0,0,0},
  {0,1,1,0},
  {0,0,0,1},
};  
for (int i = 0; i<3; ++i) {
  for (int j = 0; j<4; ++j) {
    schur[i][j] = staticArray[i][j];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My reason for not doing this is that `N` will later grow, so I don't want to be constrained by my choice now (or later) and I'm trying to optimize for performance, so lots of wasted space is no good.

Comment: @PengOne, how could defining one array to be as big as your biggest case result in wasted space? The biggest case is going to use that much anyway.

Comment: @0xbe5077ed The number of columns is 2^(N-1). Right now I'm only running up to N=5. In the future I plan to run up to N=15. Defining the array based on N=15 creates a huge amount of unused space.

Comment: Then as the comments on your post state, you will have to allocate the memory from the heap at runtime.

Comment: You're not going to be iterating over that unused space, so it's not going to waste processor power.  You may have to do some extra fetching depending on how things get cached, I suppose, but that's not a subject I know very well at all. (If that does become a problem, you can definitely take up less space than `int` but then you might have some access issues.) Still, assuming 3/5/7 for now I think it'd work reasonably well.

Comment: @AzeemBande-Ali +1 for a good enough solution for the immediate problem (N=3,4,5). Still looking for a better general solution...

Answer (score -1):

Since you're concerned about space, and since your larger arrays appear to be mostly zeros with relatively few ones, you might want to consider a "sparse array" solution. Access speed would be much slower, but the amount of memory used might be much less.

Websearching on that phrase will find implementations; which one would be best depends on how you intend to use these arrays.

Comment: Reason for downvoting, please? If you have an objection, it's a lot more helpful if we know what it was.

Answer (score -1):

```
switch (N) {
  case 3: 
    numPar = 3;
    int tmp1[3][dim] = {
      {1,0,0,0},
      {0,1,1,0},
      {0,0,0,1},
    };//then copy this rray to thry you want 
    break;

  case 4:
    numPar = 5;
    int tmp2[5][dim] = {
      {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
      {0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0},
      {0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0},
      {0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0},
      {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
    };//then copy this rray to thry you want     
    break;

  case 5: 
    numPar = 7;
    int tmp3[7][dim] = {
      {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
      {0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
      {0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0},
      {0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0},
      {0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0},
      {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0},
      {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
    };//then copy this rray to thry you want         
    break;

  default:  
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

First, note the hopefully obvious problem that you can't use variables when declaring an array in C, only constants.  For example, your first declaration could work like this:

```
int schur[][] = {
  {1,0,0,0},
  {0,1,1,0},
  {0,0,0,1}
};
```

and the compiler will happily figure out just how much space to allocate ... if, of course, you also weren't trying to declare the same variable multiple times in your switch statement.  :-)

The second thing to keep in mind is that the construct:

```
int myArray[][] = { {1, 0, ... }, { 0, 1, ... }, ... };
```

declares an array of pointers to arrays of integers.  In that example, schur is an array of 3 pointers, each of which points to an array of 4 integers.

This being C, there is of course a number of different ways to accomplish what you're trying to do.  (Steve's Law of Computing:  "If there exists one way to do something, there exists an infinite number of ways to do the same thing.")

What comes to mind first for the three cases you show above is to declare the 3 arrays you need, then just return the appropriate one from the switch statement:

```
int schur3[][] = {
  {1,0,0,0},
  {0,1,1,0},
  {0,0,0,1}
};

int schur4[][] = {
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0},
  {0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0},
  {0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}
};

int schur5[][] = {
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}
};

/* Note that what you get is a pointer to an array of pointers! */
int * * getSchurArray(int N)
{
    switch (N)
    {
    case 3:
        return (schur3);

    case 4:
        return (schur4);

    case 5:
        return (schur5);
    }
}
```

(Caveat:  No, I didn't run that through a compiler yet, so I won't guarantee there are no typos!)

Now, if you want to make this dynamic, and you really want to stick with C, you're going to have to use malloc(), which is how you do dynamic arrays in C.  In your case, you need to do something along the lines of:

```
int * * createSchurArray(int numPar, int dim)
{
    /* malloc() requires number of bytes, which is number of entries */
    /* times the size of each entry. */
    int * * answer = malloc(numPar * sizeof(int *));
    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < numPar; rowIndex++)
    {
        answer[rowIndex] = malloc(dim * sizeof(int));

        for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < dim; colIndex++)
        {
            answer[rowIndex][colIndex] = schurValue(numPar, dim, rowIndex, colIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

where implementation of:

```
int schurValue(int numPar, int dim, int rowIndex, int colIndex)
```

is left as an exercise for someone who understands what you're trying to do with Schur functions.  :-)

(Oh, wait - did I break an "only one smiley per answer" rule?)

Comment: -1. Sure you can have variables in the declaration of arrays. This is part of the language since C99. Also don't propagate the use of 2D array emulation as arrays of pointers. This belongs in a museum. And please, at least get your syntax correct.